# IF condition on MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables (Table A, Table B) with the same fields (user_id, domi, ipiresia).
Users can add values in Table A. I want these values to be inserted automatically in Table B **BUT** only when the user_id is not included in Table B.
on.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_value_added 
AFTER INSERT ON table_a
FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.user_id != user_id
  INSERT INTO table_b (user_id, domi, ipiresia)
  VALUES (NEW.user_id, NEW.domi, NEW.ipiresia);
```

I know that the IF statement is wrong because the trigger doesn't work as expected.
Any help?

Comment: try something on your own first . research , learn , than paste your effort here . it will be easy for all to help you better and faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an IF at all. Just do an `insert select` on your trigger like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_b (user_id, domi, ipiresia)
   SELECT NEW.user_id, NEW.domi, NEW.ipiresia
     FROM table_a
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from table_b where user_id = NEW.user_id);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. A small correction only...'SELECT .... FROM table_a' instead of table_b.